# Codeigniter - Return an array from where_in query

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to receive an array from a query "where_in" in Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('file_name');
$this->db->from('images_table');
$this->db->where_in('id', $id_array_img);

$result = $this->db->result_array();

print_r($result);
```

But doesn't work; why?

Comment: look at the active record documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your have forgot to do the:**

```
$this->db->get();
```

**Your model should be like:**

```
<?php
class Your_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);     
    }

    public function function_name()
    {
        $this->db->select('file_name');
        $this->db->from('images_table');
        $this->db->where_in('id', $id_array_img);            
        $query = $this->db->get();                   // add this

        $result = "";
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            $result = $query->result_array();
        else
            $result = "No result";

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Without `$this->db->get();`, you are just generating the query, but not firing it.